# Flutter Unhandled Exception:type'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String,dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

im tryin to display data from json api inside my flutter app ,
My Error :

```
E/flutter ( 2248): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

My Method:

```
Future<void> _fetchDataAkhbarGbeli() async {
    const apiUrl = 'data screen below';
    HttpClient client = HttpClient();
    client.autoUncompress = true;
        final HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(apiUrl));
    request.headers
        .set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    final HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
        final String content = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    final List data = json.decode(content);
        setState(() {
      _loadedAkhbarGbeli = data as List;
    });
  }
```

View:

```
 Expanded(
                child:ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: _loadedAkhbarGbeli.length,
                  itemBuilder:(BuildContext ctx, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(_loadedAkhbarGbeli[index]["gbeli"]["title"]),
                      );
                    },
                    )
                )
```

[image: screen]

how can i solve this problem, Thanks

**NEW Problem**

i got the same problem for this json Format using the same Method code on up just changing the API

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` is actually a map. You can get list directly like

```dart
 final List? data = json.decode(content)["gbeli"] as List?;
```

Now on use case it will

```dart
Text("${_loadedAkhbarGbeli[index]["title"]}")
```

Comment: I am making nullable for safe case, use `?` `_loadedAkhbarGbeli?[index]` if needed,

Comment: thanks bro , really you always saved my ass in flutter

Comment: Glad to help, you can check  [about json](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)  and  [my sample note parsing](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/jsonFormating/sample1.dart)

Comment: can i contact u on linkedIn or whatsapp , cuzz some problems i can't it here, and thanks

Comment: You can find my [linkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mdyeasinsheikh/) on profile, But I am not much active on social media

Comment: do u have any solution what  should i do to solve the new problem on up

Comment: You can create new question for new issue

Comment: it's done u can check it

Answer (score 1):

first create a model like this:

```
class News {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  News({@required this.title,@required this.description});
  
static List<News> fromJson(Map<String, Object> _json) {
    List<News> result = [];
    for (var item in _json['gbeli']) {
      var news = News(
          title: item['title'] as String,
          description: item['description'] as String ?? '',
          
      );
      result.add(permission);
      
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
 _loadedAkhbarGbeli = News.fromJson(json.decode(content));
```

and after that in your listview use it like this:

```
ListTile(
    title: Text(_loadedAkhbarGbeli[index].title),
)
```